# What's the difference between various Android tab navigation methods

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, material-design

I'm starting to write an Android app and want to have a tab navigation interface. It seems there are multiple choices, some of which may be deprecated:

- Android TabHost (deprecated? but still available in Android Studio)
- Tab Layout with Swipeable Views
- Android Tab Activity
- Material Design with Tabs

What is the best choice? Material Design with Tabs? How far back as far as APIs is this supported?

I know this isn't a pure coding question but it is probably a questions that others are pondering as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

extend your MainActivity to `AppCompatActivity`, and it will go till android version 7,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html

Use tabLayout and and View Pagers, To get the Swipe Effect on your Tabs

**activity_main.xml**

Add the Following to your MainActivity layout file.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
  ViewPager viewPager;
  FragmentPagerAdapter ft;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewpaggermain);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_main);
    ft = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        String [] titles = {"Subscriber","Merchant"};
        final int VIEW_COUNT = 2;
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new YourFirstFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new YourSecondFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return VIEW_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return titles[position];
        }
    };

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager.setAdapter(ft);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks asadnwfp, but I'm not sure this answers my question about which is the current preferred method and for which API. Is this the current standard for API 23?

Comment: @Jazzmine 
AppCompat is used for backward compatibility, the usage depends on the user of your app, Probably, .. its not a standard though.